# REST Query return's 403 forbidden

Tags: 2013, javascript, rest, ajax, project-server

I have problem with REST Query that should update field in project. I am sending the following Query:

```
var projectItem = {
    "projectId":  "21dba5cc-43e9-e611-80e2-02bf0a010149",
    "propertyId": '22301607-98b8-e611-80e6-02bf0a010149',
    "value": "Some example Action field value."
};

var projectUpdated = false;
jQuery.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + '/_api/ProjectServer/WorkflowActivities/updateTextProperty',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json;odata=verbose',
    data: JSON.stringify(projectItem),
    headers: {
        "Accept": 'application/json;odata=verbose',
        "X-RequestDigest": jQuery('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("jQuery ajax was finished successfully with the following prop: ");
        console.log("    Project id: " + projectItem.projectId + ","); 
        console.log("    Field id: " + projectItem.value);
        console.log("    Field value: " + projectItem.value);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log("jQuery ajax was finished unsuccessfully with the following error:");
        console.log("    data.status: " + data.status);
        console.log("    data.statusText: " + data.statusText);
        console.log("    data.responseText: " + data.responseText);
    }
});
```

And I get the following error:

```
jQuery ajax was finished unsuccessfully with ther following error:
    data.status: 403
    data.statusText: FORBIDDEN
    data.responseText: {"error":{"code":"-2130575252, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again."}}}
```

Comment: Following [Url](http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013-how-to-refresh-the-request-digest-value-in-javascript) will help you

Answer (score 1):

Try it as below:

```
var digest;
$.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/contextinfo",
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success:function(data){
            digest = data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue;
            updateItem(digest);
        },
        error:function(data){
            console.log("something went wrong")
        }
    });

function updateItem(digest){
    var projectItem = {
        "projectId":  "21dba5cc-43e9-e611-80e2-02bf0a010149",
        "propertyId": '22301607-98b8-e611-80e6-02bf0a010149',
        "value": "Some example Action field value."
    };

    var projectUpdated = false;
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + '/_api/ProjectServer/WorkflowActivities/updateTextProperty',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json;odata=verbose',
        data: JSON.stringify(projectItem),
        headers: {
            "Accept": 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            "X-RequestDigest": $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(digest)
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("jQuery ajax was finished successfully with the following prop: ");
            console.log("    Project id: " + projectItem.projectId + ","); 
            console.log("    Field id: " + projectItem.value);
            console.log("    Field value: " + projectItem.value);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log("jQuery ajax was finished unsuccessfully with the following error:");
            console.log("    data.status: " + data.status);
            console.log("    data.statusText: " + data.statusText);
            console.log("    data.responseText: " + data.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Reference - [Refresh request digest in javascript](http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013-how-to-refresh-the-request-digest-value-in-javascript)

Comment: Still return the same error.

Comment: are you using App ?

Comment: No, I am using script editor web part.

Comment: Instead of `jQuery('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()` can you use `document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value` and check ?

Comment: Both functions returns exactly the same digit.

Comment: do you have the correct permission ? I mean can you create items manually ? REST API runs on current user's permission.

Comment: Yes, I launched that script from all account including Farm Administrator. I find out that the problem was connected to project begin check out by different part of the code, and not checked in. Right now I updated other parts of the code and It is almost working. Request comes back with 200 status, however new field value is not visible until i edit the project and check it in manually...

Answer (score 1):

looks like your request token has changed:

```
jQuery('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
```

run this before the code above:

```
if (Sys.Net.WebRequestManager._events != null && Sys.Net.WebRequestManager._events._list != null) 
{ 
    var invokingRequests = Sys.Net.WebRequestManager._events._list.invokingRequest; 
    while( invokingRequests != null && invokingRequests.length > 0) 
    { 
        Sys.Net.WebRequestManager.remove_invokingRequest(invokingRequests[0]); 
    } 
}
```

looks like your token has changed giving a 403

[403 Error on REST/JSOM call within a form in SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/162293/403-error-on-rest-jsom-call-within-a-form-in-sharepoint-2013)

Comment: It returns: 
    ReferenceError: data is not defined.

Comment: just spotted the mistake. you need to remove the # , check my updated answer...

Comment: This return's undefined. Function with # reutrn's the actual digit, but overall ajax query still gives me 403.

Comment: i think your request token has changed as that should work.... please check out the updated answer

Comment: I used this code and there are no invoking request. Object is downloaded correctly, but length is equal to zero.